# How can one prove that (AD) and (EB) are orthogonal?

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

ABC is a triangle, we make outside two squares CBGD and ACEH.

I have to show that (AD) and (EB) are orthogonal. So I'm sure that there is many ways to solve this exercise.

I did it using the scalar product:
To prove that (AD) and (EB) are orthogonal we have to show that
$\vec{AD}\cdot\vec{EB}=0$.

Using theorem of shasles:
$$\vec{AD}\cdot\vec{EB}=(\vec{CD}-\vec{CA})\cdot(\vec{CB}-\vec{CE})$$
We have $\vec{CD}\cdot\vec{CB}=0$, $\vec{CA}\cdot\vec{CE}=0$ and $\vec{CA}\cdot\vec{CB}=-\vec{CD}\cdot\vec{CE}$. So using the scalar product we can prove that (AD) and (EB) are orthogonal.

But is there any other solutions with other ways?

Comment: A teacher said : Perform a 90° rotation about the point C so that B is sent to D and E is sent to A.  That rotation also sends the line segment BE to the line segment DA.  90° rotations always send lines to perpendicular lines.                                           can someone explain me this , because I cant ask him and thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $P$ be the intersection point of $\overline{AD}$ and $\overline{EB}$:
$$(\overline{CE}=\overline{CA}, \overline{CB}=\overline{CD},\angle ECB=90^0+\angle ACB=\angle ACD) \Rightarrow \triangle ECB=\triangle ACD \Rightarrow \angle CBE=\angle CDA \Rightarrow CPBD \text{ is cyclic} \Rightarrow \angle BPD = \angle BCD \Rightarrow \angle BPD = 90^0 \square.$$

Comment: Nice .. What do you used to prove it ?

Comment: To prove what? I don't understand your question, sorry.

Comment: No no just this methode how can we told it ?

Comment: It is just plane geometry look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_geometry